# Anyone know how to set Notepad++ as default text editor for SAS, Stata and R?

Tags: notepad++, r, sas

Anyone know how to set Notepad++ as default text editor for SAS, Stata and R?

I'm having the hardest time finding anything online (particularly for SAS). Looking for ability to run code from Notepad++ as well as setup color coding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For R it's `options(editor="my_favorite_editor")`.

I think your best bet for SAS is going to be assigning a key to "SUBMIT BUFFER=DEFAULT" and using the clipboard.

This - http://huebler.blogspot.com/2013/12/stata.html - might work for stata.